# Copying files in android from uri to app's private folder

Tags: android, inputstream, file-management

My app should take an image from gallery and put it into app data directory.
My implementation was that I tried sharing an image from gallery directly into the app and using its uri to copy it from its source position to the android app directory.

**After receiving the image URI:**

```
copyFile(new File(mImageUri.getPath()), getFilesDir());
```

**The copyFile method:**

```
public void copy(File src, File dst) throws IOException {
         try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src)) {
             try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst)) {
                 // Transfer bytes from in to out
                 byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                 int len;
                 while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                     out.write(buf, 0, len);
                 }
             }
         }
     }
```

The problem is that I get a FileNotFound exception, how can I fix that?

Comment: A `Uri` is not a file. Use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by your `Uri`.

Comment: I replaced file `inputStream` with this `InputStream in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(src)` but it still doesn't work. @CommonsWare

Answer (score 1):

First, use this get a file:

```
private fun openFile() {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT).apply {
        addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
        type = "application/pdf"
    }

    fileRequest.launch(intent)
}
```

fileRequest :

```
    private val fileRequest =
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { resultData ->
        resultData?.data?.also { data ->
            val myFile = File(
                requireContext().filesDir,
                "test_file.pdf"
            ) // filesDir - Your app's ordinary, persistent files reside directory
            val inputStream: InputStream =
                requireActivity().contentResolver.openInputStream(data.data!!)!!
            val outputStream: OutputStream = FileOutputStream(myFile)
            val buf = ByteArray(1024)
            var len: Int
            while (inputStream.read(buf).also { len = it } > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buf, 0, len)
            }
            outputStream.close()
            inputStream.close()
        }
    }
```

Change line `type = "application/pdf"` to specify, what king of files do you want to copy

Also, `fileRequest` is declared in fragment scope (If you don't like it, old "startActivityForResult", it will work just fine.

Also also, `openInputStream(data.data!!)`, **data.data!!** is uri of picked file